# JTable and JButton click not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JPanel holding a JButton and JScrollPane (in  turn holding a JTable) and am currently running into two issues which I believe are related:

The JButton listener's actionPerformed() method is not invoked upon click. The only way in which I can get it to be invoked is by calling doClick() on the JButton. The JButton color changes upon hover but no click animation is shown when the mouse is pressed.

Secondly, if a cell is clicked within the JTable, the cell located 2 rows down in the same column registers the click instead. This offset does not occur when clicking in the column headers (i.e. to adjust cell widths), only when within the cell area.

[Left-hand panel. Click position circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtMcK.png)

```
public class InventoryPanel extends JPanel {

// Parent Business object reference for communication and JFrame
private Business parent;
private AddItemPanel addItemPanel;
// Inventory table items
private DefaultTableModel inventoryModel;
private JTable inventoryTable;
private JScrollPane inventoryScrollPane;
private JLabel updateLbl;
private JButton addItemBtn;
// Columns for inventory table
private static final String[] INVENTORY_COLUMNS = {"Item","Stock","Restocking Level","Edit"};

public InventoryPanel(Business parent) {
    this.parent = parent;

    initGUI();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                //doStuff
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

// INITIALISES GUI
public void initGUI() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("<html><B>Inventory</B></html>");
    this.add(titleLabel);

    // Create empty inventory table
    inventoryModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[3][4],INVENTORY_COLUMNS);
    inventoryTable = new JTable(inventoryModel);
    inventoryScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inventoryTable);

    // Create button to allow items to be added
    addItemBtn = new JButton("Add item");
    addItemBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ADD ITEM PRESSED");
        }
    });

    updateLbl = new JLabel("Loading inventory...");

    this.add(addItemBtn);
    this.add(inventoryScrollPane);
    this.add(updateLbl);
}
```

I've tried removing the table from the panel to see if that solves the JButton issue and visa-versa, but no luck. I've also tried changing the project JDK but no luck there either.

There are other JPanels adjacent to the troublesome one in a JFrame which work perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Edit: I can create a working instance of the InventoryPanel alone in a frame in another project, as mentioned in the comments. However the exact same code (no calls being made to other objects/methods) in the current project now produces ClassCastExceptions. After some googling this seems to be due to non-EDT threads updating the GUI.
However there is no use of the Business class, and all GUI operations are performed using the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
            frame.add(new InventoryPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
}
```

Note: the no-argument constructor InventoryPanel() just calls initGUI().

Thanks for the help so far...still very confused by this.

Comment: Having tried your `InventoryPanel` (omitting the `Business` object), it works fine for me running JDK 1.8.0_60. Perhaps share some more of your code, namely the `JFrame`. But first try cleaning and building the project again.

Comment: ditto Java v1.7

Comment: Thanks guys, see the edit.